# Validating a DateTime with ValidationResult

Tags: c#, silverlight, validation, xaml

I'm trying to validate my DateTime objects, although I can't seem to get it working with ValidationResult. I'm able to do it for int and Strings, but how come it doesn't work for DateTime?

```
    [Required]
    [CustomValidation(typeof(DateValidator), "CrossValidateFirstDateWithSecondDate")]
    public DateTime ActiveOn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [CustomValidation(typeof(DateValidator), "CrossValidateSecondDateWithFirstDate")]
    public DateTime? ExpiresOn { get; set; }
```

Edit: It doesn't hit my break point inside my DateValidator, so nothing happens :(

**DateValidator**

```
        using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
        using System;

        namespace Fsc.Feenics.Clients.Silverlight2.Web.Models.Shared
        {
            public class DateValidator
            {
                public static ValidationResult CrossValidateFirstDateWithSecondDate(DateTime date, ValidationContext context)
                {
                    var cardAssignmentInfo = context.ObjectInstance as CardAssignmentInfo;
                    if (cardAssignmentInfo.ExpiresOn.HasValue == false) return ValidationResult.Success;
                    if (cardAssignmentInfo == null) return ValidationResult.Success;
                    return ValidateFirstLessThanLast(date, cardAssignmentInfo.ExpiresOn.Value);
                }

                public static ValidationResult CrossValidateSecondDateWithFirstDate(DateTime? date, ValidationContext context)
                {
                    var cardAssignmentInfo = context.ObjectInstance as CardAssignmentInfo;
                    if (date.HasValue == false) return ValidationResult.Success;
                    if (cardAssignmentInfo == null) return ValidationResult.Success;
                    return ValidateFirstLessThanLast(cardAssignmentInfo.ActiveOn, date.Value);
                }

                private static ValidationResult ValidateFirstLessThanLast(DateTime firstDate, DateTime? secondDate)
                {
                    return firstDate <= secondDate.Value ? ValidationResult.Success : new ValidationResult("First number in range must be less than or equal to last number in range", new string[] { "ActiveOn", "ExpiresOn" });
                }
            }
        }
```

Edit: My boss said we use "InvokeOperation" with RIA Services to send the data in one big object to the server then to our database.

Edit: It doesn't hit the breakpoint even if I make it not nullable

Comment: Could you give some more information. What happens on the validation?

Comment: Does it hit the breakpoint if ExpiresOn is not nullable?